# Access innerHTML or innerText of structural dom(*ngFor) element in selenium

Tags: java, angular, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to access innerHTML/innerText of structural DOM element but getting commented element, not getting child elements.

```
<div class="snap-box">
  <label class="snap-heading">Recommendations</label>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 snap-list" *ngFor="let rec of recommendations">
      <div class="title">{{rec.title}}</div>
      <div class="description">{{rec.description}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

in selenium i'm trying to access all title & description of snap-list, like this..

```
driver.execute_script("return document.getElementsByClassName('snap-box').innerHTML");
```

getting innerHTML as -

```
<div class="snap-box"> <label class="snap-heading">Recommendations</label> <div class="row"><!----></div> </div>
```

but expecting result all innerHTML of *ngFor. Could someone help please, Thanks in advance.

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName('snap-box') is likely returning a different element than you're expecting.

Also your html doesn't look like rendered HTML DOM.

Comment: @OmprakashSharma You have tagged [tag:java] but in your code trials you have used `driver.execute_script()`

Answer (score 0):

The `getElementsByClassName(...)` method returns a **collection** of DOM nodes. You need to access the first element in the collection before getting the innerHTML, or use the querySelector method:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('snap-box')[0].innerHTML

// OR

document.querySelector('.snap-box').innerHTML
```